# Issue with qt while using opencv

Tags: python, qt, opencv, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I tried to run simple code:

```
import cv2
import os

dir_path = './images'
images = [cv2.imread(f'{dir_path}/{file_name}') for file_name in os.listdir(dir_path)]
cv2.imshow('bike', images[0])
```

And then I got this error:

`qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "pathtoproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"`

My system:

`Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64`

Pip list:

```
numpy                    1.24.1
opencv-python            4.7.0.68
qtconsole                5.4.0
QtPy                     2.3.0
```

I tried different solutions like install pywayland, qt5-waylnad, etc. I think I should put file with plugin in /plugins dir, but I can't it.

Comment: this is a totally unrelated error.  can you run other code, like `print('hello world')` ?

Comment: `print()` and other default commands works good, the issue is exactly with `cv2.imshow()` func, cause it opens another window to show image